# Get value of hidden column in DataTable

Tags: datatables, jquery-plugins

Once a button is selected on my page I need to iterate through a DataTable, find the row with the radio button that's selected and then get the value from a hidden column on that row. I've tried just about everything but my hidden columns aren't accessible, only my 3 visible columns. My code example has several of the options I've tried to I apologize if it's a little messy. This is my first time posting so please don't get mad if I've messed something up here. I've seen the .fnGetData option but it's listed as "legacy" so I'd rather not use it (???).

Table Setup:

```
    var thisurl = '@Url.Action("Addresses", new { AddUID = "000" })';
    thisurl = thisurl.replace("000", @ViewBag.AddUID);
    
    $('#@ViewBag.TblID').dataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [0, 1],
                "visible" : false
            }
        ],
        "searching": false,
        "info": false,
        "paging": false,
        "order": [1, "desc"],
        "ajax": {
            "type": "POST",
            "url": thisurl,
            "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            "data": function (data) { return data = JSON.stringify(data); }
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Adrs_UID" },
            { "data": "revision_id" },
            {
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    var url = '@Html.RadioButton("000", "select", false, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "111", onclick = "ResetRadioBtns()" })';
                    url = url.replace("000", '@ViewBag.ChkID').replace("111", '@ViewBag.ChkID');
                    return url;
                }
            },
            {
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    return row.Adrs_One + ' ' + row.Adrs_City + ' ' + row.Adrs_St + ' ' + row.Adrs_Zip;
                }
            },
            {
                "render": function (data, type, row) {
                    var text = 'Print';
                    var target = '_blank';
                    var link = '../DocGen/DocGen_AB.aspx?AUID=' + row.Adrs_UID + '&REV=' + row.revision_id;
                    return '<a href="' + link + '" target="' + target + '">' + text + '</a>';
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

Script

```
                $('.btnAPL_DTV').click(function (e) {
                
                        var table = $('#tblAPLAddress_DTV').DataTable();
                        table.rows().every(function (value, index) {
                                node = table.row(value).node();
                                var check = $(node).find("input[id$='chbxAPLAdSelect_DTV']");
                                var data1 = $('#tblAPLAddress_DTV').DataTable().row(this).data();
                                data = data1[0];
                                
                                if (check.prop("checked") == true) {
                                    // Get Rev_Id & Adrs_UID from Hiddent Field
                                    var allData = table.row(index).data();
                                    var revData = allData[0].data();
                                    adrsUID = node.data()[0];
                                    revId = node.data()[1];
                                }
                        });
                });
```

---

---

UPDATE 08-13-2021

Andrew - Here the script code and my results from yesterday using your example (including using the index value so you can see what I did yesterday):

```
$("#tblAPLAddress_DTV").on("click", ":radio", function () {
    var table = $('#tblAPLAddress_DTV').DataTable();
    var rowNode = $(this).parent().parent()[0];
    console.log("Result using .Adrs_UID:  " + table.row(rowNode).data().Adrs_UID);
    console.log("Result using Index Value: " + table.row(rowNode).data()[0]);
});
```

And here are my results displayed in the console:

```
Result using .Adrs_UID:  undefined
```

```
Result using Index Value: <input id="chbxAPLAdSelect_DTV" name="chbxAPLAdSelect_DTV" onclick="ResetRadioBtns()" type="radio" value="select">
```

I'm not sure which HTML you're referring to. Here's my HTML table set-up. @ViewBag.TblID = "tblAPLAddress_DTV":

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-1">
        <table id=@ViewBag.TblID class="table text-nowrap" style="padding-top:1em">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Address UID</th>
                    <th>RevisionID</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Address Block</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I don't think this matters but I apologize if it does. My table HTML set-up and table definition script above are in a Partial View.
Here's the Html call in the Index View to call the PartialView:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("_Addresses", "DocGeneration", new { id = "tblAPLAddress_DTV", chkId = "chbxAPLAdSelect_DTV", AddUID = ViewBag.AddUID });}
```

Hope this gives you the info you need.

---

UPDATE 2
Updated script:

```
$("#tblAPLAddress_DTV").on("click", ":radio", function () {
    var table = $('#tblAPLAddress_DTV').DataTable();
    var rowNode = $(this).parent().parent()[0];
    console.log(rowNode);
});
```

Console results - I didn't drill down too far.

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1">
        <input id="chbxAPLAdSelect_DTV" name="chbxAPLAdSelect_DTV" onclick="ResetRadioBtns()" type="radio" value="select">
    </td>
    <td>17647 157TH STREET BONNER SPRINGS XX 66000</td>
    <td><a href="../DocGen/DocGen_AB.aspx?AUID=9546&amp;REV=3" target="_blank">Print</a></td>
</tr>
```

These console results are the same as the HTML getting generated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a simplified version of your table and code to show one possible approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [
      {
        "targets": [0, 1],
        "visible" : false
      }
    ]
  } );

  $( "#example" ).on( "click", ":radio", function() {
    var rowNode = $( this ).parent().parent()[0];
    console.log( table.row(rowNode).data()[0] );
  });

} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office in Country</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td><input type="radio"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td><input type="radio"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior "Technical" Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td><input type="radio"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td><input type="radio"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Milan</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td><input type="radio"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

(In my case, the radio buttons are not cleared after each click, because I did not add that logic.)

How this works:

I use a delegated event handler:

```
$( "#example" ).on( "click", ":radio", function() { ... }
```

This allows events to be attached to radio buttons which may not initially be drawn - for example, if they are not on page 1 of the DataTable's paginated data.

I extract the row node (the `<tr>` element) using jQuery:

```
var rowNode = $( this ).parent().parent()[0];
```

In my case, the row node is the grandparent (`.parent().parent()`) of the radio button. Your case may be slightly different. I don't know what your final rendered HTML structure is.

In my case, each row of data is stored as an array of values (not as an object), so I can use the following to access the first hidden value:

```
table.row(rowNode).data()[0]
```

Note that the `table` variable was already defined as part of the DataTable declaration.

If your row data is provided as objects `{ ... }` instead of arrays `[ ... ]`, you will need to adjust your code accordingly.

You can log `table.row(rowNode).data()` to the console to see for yourself. You haven't shown us your JSON data, but it looks as if you would need to access the named values, such as `adrsUID` - so probably this:

```
table.row(rowNode).data().adrsUID
```

Comment: Thank you for responding Andrew. I tried your code but my result is: `<input id="chbxAPLAdSelect_DTV" name="chbxAPLAdSelect_DTV" onclick="ResetRadioBtns()" type="radio" value="select">`   A row of my data looks like this: `{"Adrs_UID": 9546, "Adrs_One": "17647 157TH STREET", "Adrs_City": "B SPRINGS","Adrs_St": "XX","Adrs_Zip": "00000","Updated_Date": "/Date(1378740584860)/","revision_id": 3}`. Any ideas on what I'm doing differently?

Comment: You should edit your question and add this information there. Adding code into comments is not very effective. However... (1) If your row data uses `Adrs_UID`, then you need to use that in your version of my code: `table.row(rowNode).data().Adrs_UID`. (2) You need to show _exactly_ what your attempt looks like. Otherwise, it's just guesswork on my part. I don't really know what you mean by "my result is..", since I don't know what code you used to generate that result. (3) You also need to show the HTML you are using.

Comment: Hi Andrew (James?). I updated my question. Thx.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. First of all, what does `console.log( rowNode );` show? It should print the `<tr>` node for the row containing the clicked radio button. If it does not, then that is where I need to see the HTML generated by your code (the end result HTML, not the source HTML). This is so I can see how your radio buttons were created, and how a typical row is structured. Seeing an example of the end-result `<tr>...</tr>` HTML would be sufficient to do that.

Comment: Your `rowNode` structure looks like I would expect - so, I'm sorry, but I cannot see any obvious reason why your code behaves differently from my sample.

Comment: I appreciate your time. If I figure it out I'll post an update.